# How does llvm-ld locate libstdc++

Tags: linux, linker, llvm, ld

**Short question**:
How does `llvm-ld` locate `libstdc++`?

**Details**:

I am getting the following error message:

`llvm-ld: error: Cannot find library 'stdc++'`

while running `llvm-ld`.  I am trying to understand how `llvm-ld` searches for `libstdc++`.

I am setting up a new system and following compilation steps that work on a different system.  Eventually I noticed a difference with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that was set in my `.bashrc` on the old system that included a large number of directories including for Cadence and other miscellaneous software.  I don't want to use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I want to be able to link against `libstdc++` by supplying the appropriate command line parameters to `llvm-ld`.

The command I am running is:

```
llvm-ld -disable-internalize -native -o foo foo.bc4 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpthread -lrt  -lstdc++ -lm -v
```

which results in the following output:

```
  Linking bitcode file 'foo.bc4'
  Linked in file 'foo.bc4'
  Linking archive file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a'
  Linking archive file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.a'
llvm-ld: error: Cannot find library 'stdc++'
```

However running `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++*` results in:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Apr 15 16:34 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ->    libstdc++.so.6.0.16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 962656 Apr 15 16:36 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
```

So I don't understand why `llvm-ld` is not finding this file?  Especially since when I compile with with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set and then run `ldd` on the resulting executable I get the following output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff7ffe000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffff7dc1000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffff7ac0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffff77c6000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffff75b0000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffff71f0000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000555555554000)
```

Which seems to indicate that the version of `libstdc++` that I want is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` but I can't figure out why `llvm-ld` is not locating it with the search path `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

For reference: `uname -a` results in: `Linux FOO 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

And `llvm-ld --version`:

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 3.1svn
  Optimized build.
  Built Sep 14 2012 (13:22:38).
  Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: core2
```

Comment: It looks like `llvm-ld` isn't looking for `.so.#`. The documentation says that it only looks for `lib${library}.${shared library extension}`. Can you try making a symlink `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6`? It should still be finding the versioned `so`, though...

Comment: thanks, creating the symlink solves the problem. Although I still don't understand exactly how the linker search process works.

Comment: If you `man llvm-ld`, the search order is right at the top. Anyway, I usually link directly with `clang`, since it understands all the C++ libraries I'm looking for.

Comment: Gabriel or @Travis, please add an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `llvm-ld` isn't looking for `.so.#`. According to the `man` page:

> When looking for a library specified with the `-l` option, `llvm-ld` first attempts to load a file with that name from the current directory.  If that fails, it looks for `liblibrary.bc`, `liblibrary.a`, or       `liblibrary`.**`shared library extension`**, in that order, in each directory added to the library search path with the -L option.  These directories are searched in the order they are specified.  If the library cannot
>    be located, then `llvm-ld` looks in the directory specified by the `LLVM_LIB_SEARCH_PATH` environment variable.  If it does not find a library there, it fails.

You can make this work by creating a symlink `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so` -> `libstdc++.so.6`.

I usually link with `clang` directly, since it understands searching for C++ library things better.